# java: convert int to object of type T

Tags: java, comparison, comparable, compareto

so I have a class called **ExpandableArrayList** that implements **ListInterface**. This ArrayList is filled with instances of type **Item** (it represents my generic type T). class Item **implements Comparable** , and has the following attributes : String itemNo, String itemName, double price, and int quantity.

A method called **CheckLimit** In class ExpandableArrayList is supposed to check if any entry in the list is having a quantity below the given limit or not. If it is, it removes it and inserts it at the front of the list.

I already defined **compareTo** for class Item based on item quantity, 
and this is my current implementation for checklimit :

```
 public void checkLimit (int limit){

/*Type conversions, change limit from int to Object and then to T,   
   in order to use CompareTo: */ 
 Object limitObj = (Integer)limit; 
 T limitT = (T)limitObj; 
 for ( int i=0 ; i< length ; i++ ) { 
    if ( limitT.compareTo(list[i]) > 0){ 

        /* ....... Remove and insert at front ......  */

    } // end if 
    } // end for   
 } // end checkLimit
```

It compiles correctly but causes a runtime Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
 Item cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I then tried to add the following method to class item

```
 /* Added method ConvertToTypeT : 
this method is called by method checkLimit in class
ExpandableArrayList. it receives an integer and creates a temporary
Item Object having this integer as its quantity for comparision purpose only*/ 

public Item convertToTypeT(int limit) { 
  Item converted = new Item (" "," ",0.0,limit);
  return converted;                 }
```

and changed checklimit to be :

```
 public void checkLimit (int limit){
    for ( int i=0 ; i< length ; i++ ) {

    T  limitT =list[i].convertToTypeT(limit);
    if ( limitT.compareTo(list[i]) > 0){ 

        /* ....... Remove and insert at front ......  */

    } // end if 
    } // end for   
 } // end checkLimit
```

but did not work even after I changed the **public** Identifier

```
ExpandableArrayList.java:255: error: cannot find symbol
    T  limitT =list[i].convertToTypeT(limit);  
                      ^
symbol:   method convertToTypeT(int)
location: interface Comparable<CAP#1>
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class ExpandableArrayList
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object super: T from capture of ? super T
```

so is there a proper way to perform such a comparison ?  considering that the header of checkLimit was given in the question and it should not be changed (it should always have an int argument ).

many thanks in advance.

Comment: An `Item` and an `Integer` are completely different kinds of objects. Why are you trying to cast an `Integer` to an `Item`? Note: Casting does not somehow automatically convert an object into a different kind of object.

Comment: And another subtlety: you also cant cast your primitive "int limit" to "Integer".

Comment: @Jesper  yah , I did realize that , thats why I used the second way above ( adding a method that creates an item with limit being as its attribute).

Comment: @pbabcdefp Uups; you are correct. I guess the compiler is replacing the cast with some new Integer() or Integer.valueOf() ... interesting. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @EddyG it's done by [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: @javastudent If all you know about `T` is that it implements `Comparable<? super T>` then you don't have a way to get at `quantity` in class `Item`, and then it's going to be hard!

Comment: @Jesper 'Autoboxing' denotes the process that the compiler does "something". I was referring to the "implementation" that makes "something"  possible.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is here in your `checkLimit` method:

```
T limitT = (T)limitObj;
```

In this line you are trying to cast `limitObj`, which is an `Integer`, into type `T`, which is `Item`. You can't do this - an `Integer` is a completely different kind of object than an `Item`, there's no way to cast an `Integer` to an `Item` (and why do you think you need to do this?).

If you want to check the `quantity` value of your `Item` objects, do this:

```
public void checkLimit(int limit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (list[i].quantity < limit) {
            // do whatever you need to do with list[i]
        }
    }
}
```

(`list` has to be a list of `Item` objects for this to work).

Comment: well, I should not customize the class ExpandableArrayList for type Item only (by writing list [i].quantity) , the class should work for any type of list entries , since it was written by the author of the book I am studing  and I am only asked to used it in my program. thanks though..